# Turn ON includeexceptiondetailinfaults soap client in php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

How to turn ON `includeexceptiondetailinfaults` in soap client using PHP?

By turning ON `includeexceptiondetailinfaults`, I want to catch the exact faults.

How can I do this or any other way to catch the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

The `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` setting is a setting on the Microsoft .NET SOAP server side. The message you get from your `SoapFault` exception was generated by the SOAP service you are talking to.

You should turn on the `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` setting on the .NET system or ask the sys admin of that system to do it for you.